# Magento, photo import ( csv ) from url, no direct link

Tags: magento-1.9, csv

How do I import **CSV** a photo from a **url**?

It is not a **direct link** though. There is a link to the product page with description and a photo gallery.

here is how the link ends

> /product.php/pid-P0512Z77/

images are sorted like this:

```
/productphotos/large/P0512Z77.jpg
/productphotos/large/P0512Z77-1.jpg
/productphotos/large/P0512Z77-2.jpg
```

etc.